# Margin commands in memoir class seem to have no effect

Tags: memoir

I need to create a 5.5'' by 8.5'' slip with a title at the top and a logo in the corner. So I did this:

```
\documentclass[18pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{soul}


\setstocksize{5.5in}{8.5in}
\setlrmarginsandblock{1mm}{1mm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{1mm}{1mm}{*}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}


\HUGE

\noindent \so{TITLE}\ldots

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node[anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south east)
              {\includegraphics[width=1in]{logo}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The logo is right where it should be, but the title is lower and farther to the right than I want it, and changing the parameters in `\setlrmarginsandblock` and `\setulmarginsandblock` doesn't seem to have any effect. How can I move the title to where it needs to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `\checkandfixthelayout`, margins are not just a few lengths, it has to be checked, thus the need for `\checkandfixthelayout`, see the manual as for which options it support.

Comment: Calling `\checkandfixthelayout` produces these errors:

`Class memoir Error: \paperheight (794.96999pt) and/or \trimtop (0.0pt) are too large for \stockheight (397.48499pt) by 397.485pt. []`

`Class memoir Error: \headheight (12.0pt) and/or \headsep (18.06749pt) are too large for \uppermargin (2.84526pt) by 27.22223pt. []`

`Class memoir Error: \footskip (25.29494pt) is too large for \lowermargin (2.12473pt) by 23.17021pt. []`

Does this mean that I need to set the stock size and `\footskip` manually?

Comment: @crmdgn it means that you have not left any space for the headers and you need to set the header and footer siz so accordingly. It seems rather strange to only have 1mm margins. Memoir does not adjust the default header and footer sizes to the new stock